# The stream or file "storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel-5, centos

Please Help. My linux centos server got shutdown and after the server has started laravel give and error :

The stream or file "storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

I have give the permision to logs folder

chmod 777 -R logs.

but the error Remain.

Thank you so much for any help.

Best Regards,

Dian[image]

Comment: Try this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041196/there-is-no-existing-directory-at-storage-logs-and-its-not-buildable-permissio

Answer (score 0):

I have my solution,  after googling

This is what I done

1. cd /var/www/html
2. setenforce 0
3. service httpd restart

Regards,

Dian