# There is no existing directory at /storage/logs and its not buildable: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, permissions

I have a problem with my Laravel deployment on a OVH web server. 
After made

```
composer update

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:clear

php artisan dump-autoload
```

I have this answer:
*`There is no existing directory at /storage/logs and its not buildable: Permission denied`*

I put all the files on 777 chmod but I have always this answer.

Comment: just as a note to anyone who tries this and it is not used to artisan commands or composer (we all make the same mistake from time to time) the command is composer dump-autoload, not artisan :) cheers!

Comment: php artisan dump-autoload? you might mean 'composer dump-autoload'

Comment: In my case, I just forgot a `;` in a file... so check if you don't have errors in any files.

Answer (score 255):

Please try the following commands

```
php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

**Note:** In case you are a Homestead & VirtualBox user, please be sure that your VirtualBox is up to date.

It helped in this [thread at laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/there-is-no-existing-directory-at-storagelogs-and-its-not-buildable-permission-denied)

Comment: This sequence (route, config, then cache) worked for me!

Comment: For last command: Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Chanchal: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231248/laravel-showing-failed-to-clear-cache-make-sure-you-have-the-appropriate-permi Was a one sec search.

Comment: This works great... in my case it was also the config...
But does anyone understand what the underlying problem is? Is it an issue in the configuration? or an error in how the config cache is built (e.g. ignoring .env or something like that?)
It seems that folders are there, have the right permissions, etc. so something seems to be smelly, I just can't point at it...

Comment: Only Jesus know why this is related with `Redis error:  cannot assign requested address ` but now is fixed.

Comment: If this problem persists while running Laravel locally inside a Docker container, make sure you execute these commands inside the container.

Answer (score 138):

Clear the cache and config, then deploy to the live server.

If you've already uploaded to the live server, then you have to follow these steps:

1. Delete `bootstrap/cache/config.php`
2. Delete all log files in `storage/logs`.

Comment: The best answer for shared hosting 

Comment: I do this and it gets rid of the error stated in the question here, but then I get a 500 Internal Error in its place. Any thoughts?

Comment: Great, thanks! Worked for me with Docker.

Comment: Looks kind of crazy but it actually worked, have been messing with permissions which looked fine for hours. Yet it was not permission issue at all. Thanks much!

Answer (score 72):

**You don't need to add any permission on the storage file.**

- The main problem here is in the compiled file, and due to which laravel try to show an error.
- By default in laravel, storage file not having permission to show in the console (error
  shows from the error.log file).
- So the thing you need to fix is to fix compile file. which can be done thought this single command

Use this

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

**This command will clear all your cache**

- Compiled views
- Application cache
- Route cache
- Configuration cache

Comment:  You're a life saver! I had some stupid CORS issue and solved by the command.

Comment: I am happy that it helps. @AmirrezaNasiri 
Thanks for your comment too.

Comment: Worked, even if it said "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions." :-)

Answer (score 28):

After changing local conf i got the same error over and over,
try this, probably will help.

```
rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

and then

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

depending on your scenario, reloading auto-loader file can solve your issue, for that use :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or sometimes just try  :

```
composer install
```

this do the two the commands listed above.

Comment: Well this solve the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: just removing the config file and clearing the cache worked for me (no need for composer commands).. thx for the help

Answer (score 5):

go to your vagrant

then run

vagrant ssh

php artisan config:cache

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what this accomplishes

Comment: First you need to run your vagrant env, then you should connect to its bash script using vagrant ssh, config cache will clear the cached config files, then rebuild them.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command if you can access your server terminal

php artisan route:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache

If you are on shared hosting and cant access the terminal go to your web route file in `routes/web.php` and make a temporary link such as shown:

```
Route::get('reset', function (){
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
});
```

Then go to `http://your-domain/reset` to execute the commands. there after you can now access your website as normal

Answer (score 3):

If you are using homestead (vagrant) in Laravel then follow the steps @Farid shahidi provided

```
vagrant ssh
cd /home/vagrant/code <-- your file usually resides here; see your Homestead.yaml configuration
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: If you are using vagrant/docker/etc make sure to run `php artisan config:cache` from _inside_ the machine.

Answer (score 2):

This one-line command solves my issue:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 2):

You Have to try artisan command in this way

1. ```php
   php artisan cache: clear
   ```
2. ```php
   php artisan config:cache
   ```
3. ```php
   php artisan cache: clear
   ```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Delete bootstrap/cache/config.php from your laravel deployment on the server.

Comment: simple and working solution thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using sail, do:

```
sail artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below commands:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me in case your project is located within `/var/www/html/`

`sudo chmod -Rf 0777 /var/www/html/{project-name}/bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -Rf 0777 /var/www/html/{project-name}/storage`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command from the terminal.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I change the permissions of the folders inside the the storage folder.

`chmod 777 <folder_name>`

I'm not sure about this security wise. but this resolve my problem.

I change my file settings to `755` also work for me.

Comment: Using `777` permission is a REALLY bad permission and it has so many security issues because it give `RWX` permission to every body!

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian thanks, I change my permissions to 755 also work for me. I edit my above answer also after your comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> 1. remove your "vendor" folder
> 2. Run "composer install" or "composer install --ignore-platform-reqs" on your cmd or terminal
> 3. php artisan config:cache
> 4. php artisan config:clear
> 5. php artisan cache:clear
> 6. php artisan route:cache
> 7. php artisan view:clear
> 8. php artisan config:cache

if you are using linux:

> 9. service apache2 restart (just in case)

if you using xammp:

> 9. just restart your xammp