# Laravel showing "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Laravel was displaying to me "Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". One solution for this was clearing the cache and the config cache stored, all this with these three commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

After `php artisan cache:clear`, terminal says:

`Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.` (with red background)

Doing the second and third code (`php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`) works fine! But it still gives me the error when typing the first line. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It worked for me when I changed the sequence (route:clear, config:clear, then cache:clear).

Comment: Use sudo if none of the suggested solutions work for you. ;)

Comment: `sudo -u www-data php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: This is honestly a problem every single time... im so tired of this problem... i have like a full page of notes on how to fix this, but it seems like the list is getting longer and longer... this time around i cant fix it at all.. deleted all cached files, created all the folders, tried to halt, tried to reload provision, tried to open terminal in administrator, tried to switch my cache drivers.... tried it all, this time it just wount do the storage link, so annoying

Answer (score 439, accepted):

If the `data` directory doesn't exist under (`storage/framework/cache/data`), then you will have this error.

This `data` directory doesn't exist by default on a fresh/new installation.

Creating the `data` directory manually at (`storage/framework/cache`) should fix this issue.

Comment: I have `storage/framework/cache/data` and am still getting this message.

Comment: @JayBienvenu It should work without the data directory anyway - only `storage/framework/cache` this path must already exist (at least for newer Laravel versions 5.7+) - check if you are not overriding the default storage path and if not, check if your cache folder has sufficient permissions for webserver/php ; assuming default FileStore cache - the issue is probably happening in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php` - method `flush()` - you can start your debugging from there :)

Comment: @JayBienvenu, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54442312/2140408

Comment: Still having this error too... soooooo annoying... tried basically everything in my long list of possible solutions to this error..

Comment: When I upgrade laravel 5.8 to 6 then I faced this problem. Solution is correct.

Answer (score 140):

Try deleting these cached files under bootstrap folder:

```sh
/bootstrap/cache/packages.php
/bootstrap/cache/services.php
/bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Then run `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Cool...Its working, good option when you are working on cpanel and you dont have rights for terminal.

Comment: I tried everything, my error was `In Find.php line 287:  Authentication failed. ` config:cache, cache:clear config:clear, my cache was empty, nothing works. You save me, thanks!

Comment: Dident work.. still cant do art storage:link

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. I already had `storage/framework/cache/data` so above didn't work.

Answer (score 62):

Calling

```
php artisan config:cache
```

before

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh, that was it. I moved project's directory and running cache:clear was trying to clear the cache at old path which it didn't have access to (actually folder did not exist). Thanks!

Comment: Thats the right answer, unfortunate that it even happends with ´php artisan optimize:clear´

Comment: nothing work for me

Answer (score 47):

Just only add folder named *`data`* in `storage/framework/cache/` and try:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: added data folder in /application/storage/framework/cache, and its working. Thank you!

Answer (score 47):

Calling the following 4 commands should fix most of the permission issues on laravel.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Basically, `chown -R $USER:www-data` what this does is it set current user `$USER` as owner and `www-data` as group and `chmod -R 775` gives 7 to user,7 to group and 5 to other.

**#PS:** You need to run above command from the laravel project directory, else, you need to provide full path like /var/www/project_name/storage

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it keeps resetting to not-working.

Comment: @SumitWadhwa I don't think that's a problem, with the approach, let's say if you go with different user, or updated the permission while pulling code, then it might not work, else it should be fine. Instead, if you don't want to give permissions to current user, you could also another approach by adding user to group `www-data`, like: `sudo usermod -a -G examplegroup exampleusername`, and you just have to give permissions to `www-data` thereafter.

Comment: Thank you.  In attempting to fix something else, I had set both user and group to www-data, which apparently was causing the specified issue.  This fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

[image]

First try:

Check if there is a "data" folder inside "storage/framework/cache/".
If there is not, then create it manually. (create a new folder with name "data")

Option 2:

If there is a "data" folder inside "storage/framework/cache/".
Remove ALL existing folders inside there.

Then final, running this:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

This should fix this issue: "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions."

Answer (score 22):

In Laravel 8 I solved my issue by first running `composer dump-autoload` and then used `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: This appears to be the solution for Laravel 8 with Homestead and Vagrant. I'm sure it works in other environments as well, but this did the trick for me with these two. The other comments are largely valid when it comes to setting permissions however when doing `ls- l` to see ownership if everything appears correct this step of regenerating autoload files appears to be the quickest way to flush out anything wonky that is too hard to get eyes into.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me without requiring any permission changes, thanks! I just ran "php artisan config:cache" first and then I was able to successfully run "php artisan cache:clear".

Comment: Laravel 5.6 also works!

Answer (score 9):

You should update the permission using the below steps:

1. Check user using command "whoami" then let output is "ironman"
2. Run below command if "data" folder exists in the cache directory

`sudo chown -R ironman:ironman storage/framework/cache/data/`

This will resolve your below issue[image]

Comment: this is the only proper solution. Others are maybe correct in some cases. Maybe this solution can be apply on "storage & bootstrap/cache"

Comment: This works when you're unable to delete the `storage/framework/cache/data/` (I'm using Sail and L9)! Make sure to replace "ironman" with the output of the first command of course

Answer (score 8):

Deleting and adding back the `./storage/framework/cache/data` folder worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Delete all subfolders under:

```
storage/framework/cache/data/
```

Answer (score 4):

(For MAC Users)

Sometimes, it means current user don't have sufficient permission to the storage/framework/cache/data/ folder. Run

1. `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage/framework/cache/data/`

then

2. `php artisan cache:clear`

Hope sometimes it work for you.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was I had 'CACHE_DRIVER=memcached' in .env but didn't have memcached installed.  Switching to the file driver or installing memcached fixed the problem for me.

Comment: In addition you need to start memcached as if not it will simply fail with the "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions."

Answer (score 2):

I ran my project in a docker container, then later tried accessing it via laragon, I had similar issue, this was due to compiled configurations in `/bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

I fixed fit by running `php artisan config:clear`, this deletes the `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` file automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but noticed if you run php artisan config:clear it also by default runs cache:clear right after it so when you run it again there is not cache in it and gives that error. you only need to run php artisan config:clear. I am not sure why cache:clear fails when its ran alone but running the config:clear is a good alternative.

Here is a helpful alias i use to clear everything in the app.

```
laraclear='php artisan config:cache && php artisan config:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan telescope:clear && php artisan debugbar:clear'
```

Remove any unwanted commands that you do not use in it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't this solve it?

```
$php artisan optimize:clear
Compiled views cleared!
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
Configuration cache cleared!
Compiled services and packages files removed!
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to clear the autoloader with
`composer dump-autoload`

If that doesn't work you can manually remove the following non-tracked (usually) files to clear the autoloader and cache if they get jammed up:

`/bootstrap/cache/packages.php`

`/bootstrap/cache/services.php`

Comment: I've seen this answer (of deleting both packages and services files from bootstrap/cache folder) on another topic, but why should it be a resolution? Plus, there was no changes after removing them or using dump-autoload.

Comment: If the autoloader gets jammed up with cached configuration settings that are not what you want such as the DB connections, you can get into a place where they cannot clear.

Answer (score 1):

Giving **775** permission to the storage directory solved this problem for me.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
```

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel Homestead on Windows:

In your `.env` file, change your `CACHE_DRIVER` from `file` to `memcached`.

Run `php artisan cache:clear`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**
**update the permission :**

1. get user name by this command  : whoami
2. Run command if "data" folderexists in the cache directory.

   sudo chown -R YourUSERName:YourUSERName storage/framework/cache/data/

Answer (score 1):

```
Ubuntu 20.04 
My Problem is.
UnexpectedValueException 

There is no existing directory at "/home/mehedihasansagor/work-place/all-code/nik/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied

When I removed these files, Then the problem is solved

config.php
packages.php
routes-v7.php
services.php

php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on my vagrant/homestead VM. All the other things in this thread didn't help.

The solution was `vagrant reload --provision`

Answer (score 0):

I am running my project in Homestead.

My environment :

> Ubuntu1~20.04+
> Laravel 6.20.26

My output

[image]

display real fatal info

Edit `src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php 598:14`
original code:

```php
if (! $preserve) {
    @rmdir($directory);
}
```

debug code

```php
if (! $preserve) {
    rmdir($directory);
}
```

Then re-execute `php artisan cache:clear`
The output changed:

[image]

Then, I just resolve `Text file busy`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `APP_URL` is properly set on `.env` file. Changing `http` to `https` in the `APP_URL` variable on `.env` file solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my case, there is no cache available that's why the artisan is unable to delete or reset the cache.
2. First browse the website and allow it to create some cache then try to clear it.
3. You can check whether the cache is available or not in directory storage/framework/cache/*

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have all the directory, but we have 2 users.

1. deployer
2. www-data

The cache path are created with www-data, but the deployer has no write access . So we need to give the access to the deployer user.

```
setfacl -R -m u:deployer:rwx /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **UPDATE** the `cache` folder owner:

**First** check the current user with: `whoami // output: miratech`

**Second** run `sudo chown -R mirad:mirad storage/framework/cache/`

**Finally** re-run `php artisan cache:clear`

This error: [image]

Will be **FIXED** and you should see something similar to:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

My guess is you have a permission/ownership problem. Either set up the permissions correctly or recursively delete the cache folder manually and re-create it:

```
sudo rm -Rf storage/framework/cache
mkdir storage/framework/cache
```

Answer (score -4):

Incase non of these works for you, simply run your php artisan cache:clear command with sudo.
e.g. `sudo php artisan cache:clear`
Thank me later~!