# "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions" in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I think I am facing cache issue on Laravel

I have the file

[image]

I kept getting

[image]

> View [layouts.fe.wedding-us.index] not found.

I've tried clear the cache

```
composer dumpauto
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: laravel/slack-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravel/nexmo-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/remote
Discovered Package: htmlmin/htmlmin
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

---

```
php artisan view:clear && php artisan cache:clear
Compiled views cleared!
Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.
```

but I got

> Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.

Not sure why it complaining about permission since I ran this command to allow all already

> sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ bootstrap/

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: can you share a picture of folder structure for folder layouts?

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52330607/5928015 ?

Answer (score 17):

Did you recently upgrade from a previous Laravel version? The `Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.` may be caused by the missing folder `storage/framework/cache/data`. You can create it manually with:

```
mkdir -p storage/framework/cache/data
```

Check the [Cache paragraph](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade#upgrade-5.7.0) in the Upgrade to 5.7 guide for further details.

Comment: This is the right answer if you have a project that has been upgraded from a version prior to 5.7