# Larvel 6: Database connection "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching, config

I am a quite experienced Laravel developer but this time I have an error which drives me crazy because all config files are correct.

I have a Mac with macOS Catalina (10.15.5), using Laravel 6, mySQL (mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)) and PHP 7.4.6.

In other Laravel projects I have no problem to connect to the database with the following credentials: `127.0.0.1`, `3306`, `laravel`, `root`, `password`.

But on the current project I always get this error:
`Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

But I don't get why Laravel is using `''` as user and `'localhost'` as host. I have set the user to `root` and the host to `127.0.0.1` in the `.env` file. Do you guys have any explanation for that and how I can fix that?

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:myprivatekey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=backend
DB_HOST_BACKEND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_BACKEND=3306
DB_DATABASE_BACKEND=radlvoo_backend
DB_USERNAME_BACKEND=root
DB_PASSWORD_BACKEND=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I already have run the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Non of them are fixing the error. Also, before I had this error I had the error `permission denied` when executing one of the commands above. I fixed that with this [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231248/laravel-showing-failed-to-clear-cache-make-sure-you-have-the-appropriate-permi).

Maybe this is also helpful:
I have pushed the newest version of my project to my server. There I have to problem connecting to the database but I also had the same problem with the `permission denied` error when executing `cache:clear` or `config:clear`. However, I have a `shop.php` file under `/config` which stores URLs where I fetch data from. When I run this command which is using the `shop.php` config file to fetch the data it always is using the old `shop.php` file with old URLs even though I have run `cache:clear` and `config:clear` multiple times!

I even have connected via FTP to check the `shop.php` file but there are only the new URLs stored and not the old ones. I don't get what's the error here and if there is a connection between those errors!

Would appreciate any kind of help!
Thanks!

Comment: `DB_USERNAM_BACKENDE` doesn't seem right. Perhaps you meant `DB_USERNAME_BACKEND`? Check what you're using in database.php for your environment variables.

Comment: Nope, I just changed that. Not working as well. Same error

Comment: Can you show the relevant lines from your database.php please? And you still have a trailing E, if it's supposed to be `BACKEND`

Comment: Ohhh didn't saw the E at the end. Yes, this solved my problem. I am so sorry... what a stupid mistake...