# How to set JWT token expiary life time in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am using Laravel 8 and implement API's. Everything is working fine but **token expire after sometime in mobile app.** There is any way to set token expiry until user logout from mobile device. I have read articles and perform some changes but still stuck in this issue.
In ***Config/jwt.php*** i have change like this,

```
//    'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', null),
```

and

```
    'required_claims' => [
    'iss',
    'iat',
    'nbf',
    'sub',
    'jti',
],

//    'required_claims' => [
//        'iss',
//        'iat',
//        'exp',
//        'nbf',
//        'sub',
//        'jti',
//    ],
```

In auth controller i have login as,

```
$user = User::where('mobile', $request['mobile'])->first();

    if ($user){
        if(!$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)){
            return $this->responseWithError('Phone Number is Incorrect!', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }else{
        return $this->responseWithError('Phone Number does not exist!', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Anyone can help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: As of today `env('JWT_TTL', null)` may not work.

The reasons are described here: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1979

Comment: Then what's for today?

Comment: You could set it to a longer duration. But you should be looking at refresh token behavior IMHO. Because the longer the token is valid, the more time the hackers will have to break it.

Comment: How to set longer duration?

Comment: you can do `env('JWT_TTL', 1000000)`

Comment: First i add it in env? Please can you explain it. Thanks for your time

Comment: Sure! add a line `JWT_TTL=1000000` to your .env file and maybe run `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Another thing is that if user is logout then mobile app developer getting error 401 not proper response how can i handle this?

Comment: After php artisan cache:clear i got this error Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52330607/4886202