# "sudo php artisan cache:clear" Failed to clear cache, even tho i am root & Invalid Cache path

Tags: php, linux, laravel, amazon-web-services, caching

So i am running a Laravel 5.7.29 with PHP 7.2.34 on an EC2 in AWS running Amazon linux 2, i have fully set up the project and tried to run it, but whenever i connect using my EC2 Public IP and the port i get this error: [image: Please Provide a Valid Cache path]

I first check .env and ensured that CACHE_DRIVER=file, then i check config/cache.php and ensured

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

was there as well as

```
'file' => [
     'driver' => 'file',
     'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
],
```

Then i saw the project didn't make "storage/framework/cache/data", so i made the folder and made sure to give both it and bootstrap/cache reading & writing permission with

```
sudo chmod -R 775
```

then to double check i used

```
ls -la
```

to check permissions and all of them were owned by root, after all of this i did

```
sudo php artisan cache:clear
```

And still got this[image: Failed to clear cache], what was more confusing is I used sudo and still got the error then I tried to run the server and curl the localhost and surprisingly it worked with no errors being thrown, been stuck with this issue for at least 2 days, is there any solutions to this?

Edit 1: I cloned the repo again in a different directory and tried all the other steps and still got the same error, weirdly when I did `chown -R 777 bootstrap/cache storage` I still got the permission error, then I revered it back to 775

Edit 2: I have contacted a person from the team who is working on the project to discuss the issue, hopefully it will get resolved, thank you all for the suggestions and kindness ^^

Edit 3: I have finally managed to fix the error, after contacting the developer he told me that `php artisan cache:clear` will look at a file named `dstore` for cache, but the file doesn't exist, so i made `dstore/framework/cache/data` and it worked, thank you all for the help ^^

Comment: Just to clarify question but, can you normally run commands (apt install) using sudo?

Comment: i am using yum since this is amazon linux 2 but yes i can

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52330607

Comment: or this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/54442312 when you delete, use `sudo rm -rf ...` then run artisan command without sudo

Comment: Still got the same issue "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions."

Comment: which one did you do?

Comment: did you try other answers on the SO? since there are a lot of upvoted answers

Comment: Yep, i did a lot of digging before asking, i did the one you suggested and the one says to make /data in storage/framework/cache/data

Comment: Can you git pull again your project without sudo? Try to deploy your app in `/home/<user>/project` instead so that you can pull without sudo command.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did as you suggested and I still get the permission error for some reason, I got both `bootstrap/cache` and `storage/framework/cache/data` available, and still get the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue after contacting the developer, `php artisan cache:clear` looks for a custom `dstore` directory instead of the default storage, i made `dstore/framework/cache/data` and run the cache clear command again and it worked, thank you all for the suggestions and kindness ^^

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `sudo` infront of `php artisan` command. `sudo` is a program for Unix-like computer operating systems that enables users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser. Whereas Artisan is the command line interface included with Laravel.

In short, simply run:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Still got the same error sadly

Answer (score 0):

When I had issue with permission in laravel app, I ran these commands to resolve the issue. Manually creating necessary folders within `storage/framework` folder, then change the owner and the permission for `bootstrap` and `storage` folders

```
mkdir -p storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache}

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: I am using Laravel build-in http development server, so www-data is an invalid group, i am not that knowledgeable about PHP or Laravel

Comment: And if you try to set the owner to `$USER:$USER`  (the current user)? `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER storage`

Comment: I still get permission error "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions."

Answer (score 0):

As you are using amazon linux you may not find `chmod -R www-data:www-data storage` command as useful. By default amazon linux use `ec2-user`  as user. So you should first find your current user name by using command `whoami`; After that, you should sufficient permission based on server user groups. I am not confirm you are using apache or nginx for deploying your project.

Then you should give proper group permission to storage and cache directory by

`chmod -R $USER:$USER storage`

`chmod -R $USER:$USER bootstrap/cache`

Comment: Did work sadly, i tried even chmod -R 775 and it didn't work