# Laravel No Existing Directory at "storage/logs"

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-5.7

I want to run a Laravel 5.7 application with Docker. My containers start OK but when I try to run the app in the browser I get an error.

> There is no existing directory at
> "/Users/user/projects/laravel/application/storage/logs" and its not
> buildable: Permission denied

I changed permissions for the whole project with...

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/user/projects/laravel/application
```

However, nothing changed. How else can this issue be solved?

Here is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
    - "./vhosts.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhosts.conf"
    - "./application/public:/var/www/html/application/public"
    - "./:/var/www/html"
    - "./logs/nginx/error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log"
    - "./logs/nginx/access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
    environment:
    - NGINX_HOST=ld2.web
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - php
  php:
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - "./application/storage/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
    - "./application/public:/var/www/html/application/public"
    - "./:/var/www/html"
```

Here is an output of **ls -ls application**

```
drwxrwxrwx  26 user  staff     832 Oct 24 14:50 .
drwxrwxrwx   8 user  staff     256 Oct 24 01:06 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff     213 Sep  4 16:12 .editorconfig
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff     704 Oct 24 00:38 .env
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff     655 Sep  4 16:12 .env.example
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff     111 Sep  4 16:12 .gitattributes
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff     177 Sep  4 16:12 .gitignore
drwxrwxrwx   7 user  staff     224 Sep  4 16:12 app
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff       0 Oct 24 14:56 application.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff    1686 Sep  4 16:12 artisan
drwxrwxrwx   4 user  staff     128 Sep  4 16:12 bootstrap
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff    1527 Sep  4 16:12 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff  148959 Oct 24 00:35 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx  15 user  staff     480 Sep  4 16:12 config
drwxrwxrwx   6 user  staff     192 Sep  4 16:12 database
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff    1022 Sep  4 16:12 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff    1134 Sep  4 16:12 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx  10 user  staff     320 Sep  4 16:12 public
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff    3924 Sep  4 16:12 readme.md
drwxrwxrwx   6 user  staff     192 Sep  4 16:12 resources
drwxrwxrwx   6 user  staff     192 Sep  4 16:12 routes
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff     563 Sep  4 16:12 server.php
drwxrwxrwx   6 user  staff     192 Oct 24 01:20 storage
drwxrwxrwx   6 user  staff     192 Sep  4 16:12 tests
drwxrwxrwx  40 user  staff    1280 Oct 24 00:41 vendor
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user  staff     537 Sep  4 16:12 webpack.mix.js
```

**ls -la application/storage**

```
drwxrwxrwx   6 user  staff  192 Oct 24 01:20 .
drwxrwxrwx  27 user  staff  864 Oct 24 15:44 ..
drwxrwxrwx   4 user  staff  128 Sep  4 16:12 app
drwxrwxrwx   7 user  staff  224 Sep  4 16:12 framework
drwxrwxrwx   2 user  staff   64 Oct 24 01:20 logs
drwxrwxrwx   3 user  staff   96 Oct 24 00:43 php
```

Comment: /users ? are you sure that folder even exists?

Comment: Well, have you tried creating the directory?

Comment: Has this code been tested/developed on a windows host perhaps?

Comment: are you mapping a local folder to your docker container? if so, you need to use the mapped location.

Comment: @YouriKoeman , yes, I am sure that directory exists. The code was developed on Mac

Comment: @miken32 , I've created the directory and everything was OK. I also tried to run with created directory and without

Comment: @MrE, Yes, I mapped folder and mapping was successful

Comment: do you have docker configured in nu s uid mode?

Comment: @Anastasia , can you show your Dockerfile contents or docker-compose.yml in case you're using compose? The question MrE asked was: 1. if you really pass your directory into the container as a volume when launching it; 2. you used COPY command in your Dockerfile only when building the image and there was no logs at the time of the image build

Comment: you can just update your question with contents formatted :) You can also update your question with the output of the following commands: `ls -la ./application`, `ls -la ./application/storage` and I think you can just remove extra volume mount from your docker-compose.yml `"./application/public:/var/www/html/application/public"` since you already mount the whole `"./:/var/www/html"` in both nginx and php containers

Comment: @Alexey I've updated the question, thanks)

Comment: This is the solution to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041196/there-is-no-existing-directory-at-storage-logs-and-its-not-buildable-permissio/55474102#55474102

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no existing directory at /storage/logs and its not buildable: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041196/there-is-no-existing-directory-at-storage-logs-and-its-not-buildable-permissio)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that your APP_LOG_FILE in the config references the logfile path for your host machine (i.e. `/Users/user/projects/laravel/application/storage/logs`) and set as absolute path, but inside your containter the path is different and in fact is `/var/www/html/application/storage/logs`. Can you change it in the .env and try again?

Comment: I've tried to add `APP_LOG_FILE=laravel.log`, ran `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache` but it didn't work. I also tried to mount log directory to another one in container but it didn't help as well. Maybe I was doing something wrong?

Comment: can you update the question with the error message if you set your `APP_LOG_FILE=/var/www/html/application/storage/logs/laravel.log` ?

Comment: message did not change. It was blaming `/Users/user/projects/laravel/application/storage/logs` directory

Comment: ok, can you do the following: launch your containers with `docker-compose up`, then to `docker ps -a` and copy the name of php container. Then `docker exec -it <name of php container> bash` and then once you're in the container's bash, show the output of `cat .env`

Comment: I checked `.env` file inside container, line `APP_LOG_FILE=/var/www/html/application/storage/logs/laravel.log` is there but I still get the same problem

Comment: your advice helped! It was just necessary to run `php artisan cache:config` inside container but not on host machine) Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 17):

Try this command,

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

If php artisan gives error then execute,

```
composer update
```

Comment: thanks. It worked for me. Once optimised, you need to configure cache again with php artisan config:cache and then run php artisan storage:link

Comment: I've been using Laravel for years and had my go-to clear command mapped to: ```php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan clear-compiled``` I knew of optimize but it broke my app more often than not (containers, permissions). optimize:clear is new to me. And it works like a charm. Wow. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need execute `php artisan config:cache` command in container folder instead of your OS folder.
Enter in your php container:
`docker exec -it your-php-container /bin/bash`
go to laravel project folder and configure cache:
`php artisan config:cache`