# Key path "file:///home/vagrant/code/ ... /storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable

Tags: php, permissions, vagrant, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

So here is my situation. I am trying to test my `API` using `Postman` and when I hit the url:

```
https://domain.test/oauth/access_token
```

I get the following error:

> Key path
> "file:///home/vagrant/code/ ... /storage/oauth-private.key"
> does not exist or is not readable

Now when I change the `permissions` of this particular file to be `777` then it renders the following error:

> Key file
> "file:///home/vagrant/code/ ... /storage/oauth-private.key"
> permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of 777

I have already tried different solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041196/there-is-no-existing-directory-at-storage-logs-and-its-not-buildable-permissio).

how can I resolve this now? It has come to a deadlock!

My `PHP` version is `7.3`, `Laravel` version is `5.6.*`. And I am using `Laravel Passport`. And off course i am using `Homestead`. And I am on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Here is the stack trace:

```
[2020-12-09 08:36:02] local.ERROR: Key path "file:///home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Key path \"file:///home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/storage/oauth-private.key\" does not exist or is not readable at /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:45)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationServer.php(99): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\CryptKey->__construct('file:///home/va...')
#1 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php(209): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\AuthorizationServer->__construct(Object(Laravel\\Passport\\Bridge\\ClientRepository), Object(Laravel\\Passport\\Bridge\\AccessTokenRepository), Object(Laravel\\Passport\\Bridge\\ScopeRepository), 'file:///home/va...', 'file:///home/va...')
#2 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php(100): Laravel\\Passport\\PassportServiceProvider->makeAuthorizationServer()
#3 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(764): Laravel\\Passport\\PassportServiceProvider->Laravel\\Passport\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(601): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('League\\\\OAuth2\\\\S...', Array)
#6 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('League\\\\OAuth2\\\\S...', Array)
#7 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(900): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('League\\\\OAuth2\\\\S...')
#8 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(828): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(795): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#10 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('Laravel\\\\Passpor...')
#11 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(601): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('Laravel\\\\Passpor...', Array)
#12 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('Laravel\\\\Passpor...', Array)
#13 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(226): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('Laravel\\\\Passpor...')
#14 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(796): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->getController()
#15 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(757): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->controllerMiddleware()
#16 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(678): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->gatherMiddleware()
#17 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#18 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(642): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(608): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#20 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(597): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/app/Http/Middleware/SslRedirect.php(22): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Phirater\\Http\\Middleware\\SslRedirect->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(111): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#46 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
```

Comment: Did you try changing the permissions to 600 or 660? Also, I don't know how you're instantiating things, but the [AuthorizationServer](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/020faf48110632989aaa3e3893cd2bd06855bebb/src/AuthorizationServer.php#L92) takes a key as a fourth parameter that can be either a string for a file, or a [CryptKey](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/020faf48110632989aaa3e3893cd2bd06855bebb/src/CryptKey.php#L37). If you manually create the latter, you can specify `false` as the third parameter to turn that check off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Turns out my passport was not updated. I updated it to 6.0 and the issue is resolved.