# Laravel migration error throwing directory from old host even after migration to new host

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, migration, laravel-migrations

I migrated my laravel saas site from one host to another but its throwing error:

There is no existing directory at "/home4/username/abc.com/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied.

How it fix it? Please help.

I gave permissions to the logs folder and even changed the database but still the issue and the path it is showing belongs to my old host but I have migrated my website to new host.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no existing directory at /storage/logs and its not buildable: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041196/there-is-no-existing-directory-at-storage-logs-and-its-not-buildable-permissio)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the `.env` file on the new host.

Verify the user running `apache2` or `nginx` has correct permissions to these Laravel folders.

```bash
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap/cache
```

In the `config/logging.php`, check folders and code there for logging.

Clear all cache

```bash
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: I am sorry to ask but I am complete new to laravel and how can I clear all cache as the site is hosted with my hosting provider. pls help.

Comment: I have checked .env file regarding the database and user and the logs folder does have permission. I also checked logging.php and here I see logs folder defined for logging.

Comment: can you show me your logging.php and .env which user you are using and which compiler